# Push and Pull with SASS/Susy

Tags: sass, susy

I have a three divs layout and want to place them in one line:

Main | Aside | Box

```
main {@include span (8 of 17);
aside {@include span (4 at 9 of 17);
.box {@include span (2 at 13 of 17) @include pull(2);
```

I dont get the .box to leave space between itself and aside. With the code above the .box will be placed over main. Without the

```
@include pull(2)
```

it will be placed direct right. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tested also different float-right on the .box- div. Also push(2).

Comment: Either I don't understand the problem, or I can't reproduce it. Here's a working [demo on SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/c7c14a3ae4ef22d892a6). I'm not sure why you need to push or pull the last one. Notice also that the `at x` syntax only works for `isolation` output, which pulls elements from the flow, and positions them off the left edge. I don't recommend it except in very specific cases. In your case, that bit isn't doing anything.

Comment: @EricMSuzanne thanks for your time. Your demo is quite good. But not what i want. I want the Box div on position 15,16,17 and 2 "empty" cols between box and aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pull` mixin adds *negative left margins* to an element, pulling it to the left. The `push` mixin adds positive left margins, pushing it right. But in this case, you can just float the element right, which is what happens when you add the `last` keyword. What you want to do is span the last 3 columns out of 17, so in this case, you can just write that:

```
.box { @include span(last 3 of 17); }
```

see http://sassmeister.com/gist/c7c14a3ae4ef22d892a6

Comment: Great help. Thanks Eric.